# simple microcontroller program but wrong result

Tags: 8085

This is my very first simple program on 8085 microcontroller, aiming to multiply 12*9
so I have written the code as follows:

```
   MVI A,12
   MVI B,12
   MVI C,08

   SUM: ADD B
   DCR C
   JZ FINISH
   JMP SUM

   FINISH:HLT
```

but the compiler is giving A2 as result as you can see :
[image]

so where is the fault? is my code is faulty or the compiler?

Comment: Seems that default radix interprets **12** as hex. which is **18** (decimal).

Comment: @glen_gleek i see, it is really helpful to point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is correct, as the numbers are in hexadecimal.

12H = 18d

8H = 8d

12H * 9H = 18d * 9d = 162d = A2H